# THREE js imported OBJ model [.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0

Tags: javascript, three.js

I get thousands of errors (google chrome):

```
[.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.
```

OBJ and MTL files exported from Bledner, using OBJMTLLoader.js as loader
After moving to R73.

Any experience?

Comment: I got this error from a mesh exported from blender. Two things I did which seemed to help:
1. Select your object, go into edit mode, press `a` to select all faces, then press `w` and from the menu choose **Remove Doubles**. This will remove duplicate vertices.

2. Select your object, go into edit mode, press `a` to select all faces, then press `space`, and type "Select Loose Geometry", hit enter, then press `x` to delete anything selected, then click `vertices`. Press `x` again and select `edges`. Press `x` again and select `faces`. I don't know if its necessary to do all of these.

Comment: Remove Doubles is not good idea, especially if you using EdgeSplit or another functions dependent on splited faces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens when the low level render call was told to draw zero vertices/faces. It is because you have one or more meshes with a polygon that has zero faces/vertices, so on each draw call this error piles up.

The problem could be your model or it could be the export/import process. If it's the model, then below is a loose idea about how to find the problematic areas. I don't recommend using OBJMTLLoader with ThreeJS and Blender, because ThreeJS ships with a Blender plugin for exporting, and it works.

```js
checkMesh = function(mesh, child_index) {
  if (
    mesh.geometry.faces.length > 0 &&
    mesh.geometry.vertices.length > 0
  ) {
    // do stuff here with the good mesh

    for (var i = 0; i < mesh.children.length; i++)
      if (!checkMesh(mesh.children[i], i))
        i--; // child was removed, so step back

    return true;
  } else // empty mesh! this causes WebGL errors
  {
    if (mesh.parent != null)
      mesh.parent.children.splice(child_index, 1);

    console.log(mesh.name + " has zero faces and/or vertices so it is removed.");
    mesh = null;

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what could be wrong without seeing your code, but I would suggest trying JSON export and import. In three.js sourse, go to utils/exporters/blender and install JSON exporter (check readme.md). Then export your model to JSON checking carefully exporting options (type of geometry, UVs, textures). Then, you can import your model like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("model.json", function(geometry, material) {
    var m = new THREE.MultiMaterial(material);
    var o = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, m);
    scene.add(o);
});
```

I did not compare to OBJ/MTL, but in comparison to Collada, JSON loader is way faster.

Comment: Is not possible to switch from OBJ files to JSON for me.