# Three.js- RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0

Tags: three.js, webgl, rendering, render, chromium

Using three.js

On my home PC with Nvidia GNU, I get about 105 of these in my browser console:

`/#/home:1 [.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0`

But on my intel GNU laptop, I do not. Is this a disagreement with the GNU driver? Or is this something I can fix?

```
var animationId;
var CAMERA_POSITION = 5000;
function runClouds() {
  var speed = 0.8;
  cloudsContainer.style.display = 'block';
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame( runClouds );

  camera.position.y = -75;

  if (camera.position.z <= 0) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
    camera.position.z = CAMERA_POSITION;
    cloudsContainer.style.display = 'none';
    return true;
  } else if (camera.position.z <= 400) {
    speed = 0.1;
  } else if (camera.position.z <= 900) {
    speed = 0.3;
  } else if (camera.position.z <= 2000) {
    speed = 0.7;
  }

  camera.position.z -= 100 * speed;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Can you also attach scene initialisation code (maybe abbreviated)? Or link to jsfiddle with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288245/three-js-imported-obj-model-commandbuffercontextrender-warning-render-count

Comment: I'm also having this issue. If you compare the first URL to the second I'm getting [.WebGL-0x7fb74f0db200]RENDER WARNING: Render count or primcount is 0.
51[.WebGL-0x7fb74f0db200]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
bung.php:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.  a) https://www.funk.co.nz/aminosee/  (OK) b) https://www.funk.co.nz/aminosee/bung.php (BROKEN)

Answer (score 9):

This warning is thrown when Three.js is trying to render an object that does not exist yet.

Take, for example, a program here you draw a line.

If you add the line to the scene before you add any points, this warning will appear UNTIL the first point is added and a line can be seen.

If you get this, either something is waiting to be added to the scene, or in your case, since you say you get about 105 every time, I assume that an object is added to the scene then due to asychronicity, is actually made in another function after the fact.

Since it is a warning, there isn't much to be afraid about.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking it could be this from another SO post. But the fact it is on my PC but not on my laptop makes me wonder if it something else.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem because I didn't pass a `position` attribute to a `BufferGeometry` object.  Although my shader overrides `position` with its own computation, it seems to be a required attribute.

I solved this with:

```
const positions = new Float32Array(PARTICLE_COUNT * 3);
myGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
```

The default values of 0 are fine if you're not using the value in your shader.

Comment: I'm in the same boat! It seems so wasteful to pass a big buffer to the gpu for no purpose! Why would this attribute be required?